# VCS completely ignoring readmemb "not loaded"

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I am trying to write a simple test bench using a txt file to read numbers into my test bench.

I have the following test bench

temp_tb.v

```
module temp_tb();

logic clk;
logic rst;
logic [0:31] data [639:0];
logic output_valid;
logic [0:31] output_data_r [63:0];
logic [0:31] output_data_i [63:0];

top_level t0(
        .clk(clk),
        .rst(rst),
        .data(data),
        .output_valid(output_valid),
        .output_data_r(output_data_r),
        .output_data_i(output_data_i));

// set up clock
// tests
initial begin
    $readmemb("song.mem", data);
    // put your tests here
    $vcdpluson;
    
    
    rst = 1'b0;
    clk = 1'b0;
    #100
    clk = 1'b1;
    #100
    clk = 1'b0;
    #100
    clk = 1'b1;
    #100
    rst = 1'b1;
    clk = 1'b0;
    #100
    clk = 1'b1;
    #100
    clk = 1'b0;
    #100
    clk = 1'b1;
    #100
    rst = 1'b0;



    for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++) begin
        clk = ~clk;
        #100;
    end
    $finish;
end
endmodule
```

And a code file song.mem that reads

```
00000000000000000000010000000000
00000000000000000000010000000000
00000000000000000000010000000000
00000000000000000000010000000000
00000000000000000000010000000000
00000000000000000000010000000000
00000000000000000000010000000000
// etc etc etc etc
```

However when I run this test bench using VCS it does not spit out any errors however the waveform looks like this

[image: Not Loaded]

All code files and the memory are in this folder.

Previously I had the width of the data logic wrong and it showed up in the log. However I see no errors in the log right now. Is it possible that it should maybe be [31:0] rather than [0:31] I have seen this elsewhere but am not sure what it means. The goal is to have 640 integers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your simulation has started? [31:0], [0:31] makes no difference, even if the dimensions are wrong it will load.

The packed dimension is extended extended with zeros if variable is wider than file data, but the memory is not loaded if the file data is wider than the variable.

If data has more lines than the file then it will fill the initial entries with the data in the file, the remaining will keep 'xxxxx'. If the data has less lines it will fill the variable with the initial lines in the file.

You could $display something after $readmemb.

This would show the content of the memory in the log after loading

```sv
    $readmemb("song.mem", data);
    foreach(data[i]) $display("%h", data[i]);
```